# UITableView stops scrolling enough after I add/remove a view to the superview of table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here is the problem that I'm facing. I have UITableView inside main view. When user taps menu button, view is added to the view hierarchy of superview, and this view covers all screen, except the menu button. That is I call

```
[self.view insertSubview:self._menuView belowSubview:self._menuButton]
```

After user clicks the menu button again I call

```
[self._menuView removeFromSuperview]
```

However, after this, the UITableView stops scrolling, actually it scrolls, but just a little, couple of pixels, and then bounces back to the location on which it was before I inserted _menuView. I've monitored the menu hierarchy after inserting and removing the _menuView, it is actually removed, and also there is no view which covers the UITableVIew, so there is no chance that some other view steals touches from UITableView. What can be the problem? Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:** I've noticed besides not being able to scroll, another strange thing happens. When I show menuView, the tableView is scrolled to top, without animation. (the menuView is half opaque only, so I can see the tableView underneath it)

**EDIT 2:** I've monitored contentSize and contentOffset of tableView before and after inserting _menuView, the reason for not being able to scroll is that somehow contentSize is being changed.

```
TABLE VIEW BEFORE INSERTING MENU - contentSize:{Width=320, Height=10519} contentOffset:{X=0, Y=3980}
TABLE VIEW AFTER INSERTING MENU - contentSize:{Width=320, Height=44} contentOffset:{X=0, Y=0}
```

As You can see, the height is changed to 44 that's why I'm not able to scroll. And Also, as I've said in **EDIT 1:** tableView is scrolled to top - so as you can see contentOffset is also zeroed. Any ideas why content size changes automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the menuView a tableview with the same delegate/datasource ?

Comment: No, tableView's datasource/delegate is a separate object. And has nothing to do with menuView.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is problem with your tableview frame. right after removing subview, try to set frame of your tableview at its original frame.may this will solve your problem

Comment: ACtually as I've said, I monitor the UIViews before and after inserting, and the frame is not changed.

Comment: I can, but screenshots are static, and I don't think that it will help to determine the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Content in the UITableView organized automaically and designed only to show cells & header/footer elements. To proper working you should wrap your table into parentView and add your menu to that parentView rather than to the UITableView. You can also try to call reloadData method on table since it can restore the content size of the view.

Comment: I don't add menu to UITableView, As I've described in my question I add the tableView to superview (parent view). I don't want to reload data. I want to understand why adding another view effects to behaviour of UITableView.

Comment: It seems your code do execute some methods on the UITableView or its datasource when menu appears. It can't be possible to expose that behaviour without it (menu and the UITableView are siblings right?). May be you have missed some callbacks or other events? Other thing may be navigation bar& internal content offset issues but I assume that your parent view is a blank view.

Comment: For now I can't think of any one issue you have told. I'll write the answer if I find it. Thank you for answer.